# Why is it highlighted in red here - <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME"/>

Tags: android, permissions

I am trying to sign an APK file, that is, add permission to change the system. In particular, the time change on android. I follow the example https://russianblogs.com/article/14971784004/. But I have this highlighted in red in the Manifest file - android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME". So I can't even set a signature. I didn't find any answers anywhere. Tell me, please, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying use

> reverse engineering

First for that you must sign application with key , so please read about [apk tool](https://androidp1.ru/dekompilyatsiya-apk-prilozheniya-android/)